# Magento ver. 2.4.4 Qty is not getting decresed even after completing order

Tags: magento2, qty

I have upgraded magento with Magento ver. 2.4.4.

ISSUE: The quantity of a product does not decrease when the customer places an order. Instead, the salable quantity gets reduced. **(WHICH IS FINE)**

**While the quantity of the product does not even decrease even after shipping is completed.**

I have done reindex, cache flush.
But does not work.

Comment: any thoughts on it ?

Comment: are you using MSI or not?

Comment: No I have disabled MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the setting "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" in Stores > Configuration > Inventory to "Yes".